# Regression: OLS: residual split

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, estimation, heterogeneity

A friend of mine is estimating the following model, using ols:

$y=\alpha + \beta X + u$,

where $y$ and $X$ are continious variables, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters and $u$ is an error component. In a second step, he then splits the sample at the median of the residuals. He then estimates the following regression:

$y=\alpha + \beta X + \gamma Dummy(above\_Median=1) + \delta X \times Dummy(above\_Median=1)$ + v,

where $Dummy(.)$ is one if an observation is above the median and zero otherwise. My feeling is that this procedure is extremely strange and the estimates are probably biased. But I currently cannot depict/formalize the problem. What potential problems do you see? Can this be done? What do you think about this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

This amounts to discretizing (specifically: dichotomizing) a continuous variable. Your friend fits a model that has a discrete jump as an observation moves from the "below median" to the "above median" group. This almost certainly doesn't make sense. Read more here: [What is the benefit of breaking up a continuous predictor variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/1352)

If there is remaining nonlinearity, which you could detect, e.g., in plotting residuals against actuals or against fitted values, then it's far better to refit a model with [splines](/questions/tagged/splines).

*Friends don't let friends discretize continuous variables.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just as a follow up. His problem is that residuals in his model have "a deeper interpretation" and he is interested in modelling heterogeneity in this componend (i.e. heterogeneity in $\beta$). I don't see how this can be done without using sort of a proxy for the residuals.

Comment: Hm. Is he looking for an [tag:interaction] term? Or does he want to model [tag:heteroskedasticity]?

Comment: He is rather interested in interaction terms.

Comment: Then I'd recommend that he explicitly models it as such.

Comment: This is what I also proposed, but the strange thing is that he is interested in interactions with the residual. So it always needs to be a two step procedure; to me, an interaction with the residual looks extremely strange.

Comment: Well, to me it does, too. An interaction with residuals sounds very much like conditional heteroskedasticity to me. If you have a statistician available, I'd recommend your friend buy him a cup of coffee and explain his setup to him.